# Using file name to get gnu make prerequisites

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gnu

Based on the shared lib name I would like to automically figure out which SRCS to include in the make recipe.

```
SHARED_LIBS  := libc.so \
                libd.so

libc.so,SRCS  := a.o \
                 b.o
libc.so,DEPS  := -lc

libd.so,SRCS  := e.o \
                 f.o
libd.so,DEPS  := -lc


all: $(SHARED_LIBS)
.PHONY: all

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $^ -o $@ 

%.so: $($*.so,SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $($*,DEPS)
```

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? How does that makefile relate to the question? What is the intended result of that makefile?

Comment: You seem to have a specific library-naming convention in mind; if you tell us what it is, maybe we can advise you.

Comment: Basically where you see %.so currently I need to use $(libc.so,SRCS) or $(libd.so,SRCS) but I would like it to automatically grab those based on the shared lib name.

Answer (score 0):

What you have ALMOST works: the DEPS will work (if you use the correct name).

Just for clarity I'm renaming the library because you should definitely not create a library named `libc`.

If you can let go of the idea that the list of objects should be in a variable and instead declare them directly, you can do what you want pretty easily:

```
SHARED_LIBS  := libfoo.so

all: $(SHARED_LIBS)
.PHONY: all

libfoo.so: a.o \
           b.o

libfoo,DEPS := -lc

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $^ -o $@ 

%.so:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $($*,DEPS)
```

should do it.  Of course, you don't need to explicitly add `-lc` to your link line, and you probably should not do so.  But presumably you have other libraries you want to add.

If you really want the objects to be stored in a variable as well then you need to do something more fancy.

Comment: This does not seem to work. I see the .o files generated but do not see libfoo.so generated.

Comment: There was one minor change needed (move the `all` target) but it will still build `libfoo.so`.  Sorry but if you use the above makefile and run `make` then the behavior you report (`libfoo.so` is not generated) can't happen, so there must be some other aspect to your environment you haven't described here.  You can try running `make -d` and examine the (voluminous) output to determine how make decides to handle the `libfoo.so` target.

Comment: I know the question included the `%.o: %.c` rule, but that isn't really needed, is it?

Comment: It's not needed if the built-in rule is sufficient for their purposes, no.